# how to import a python class from different mains at different level of indentation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to structure a program with several modules as it is customary for python.

I have several modules containing classes and functions, and a usual main entry point.
Now I have built a different main that serves another (larger) purpose.

My structure is something like this:

```
-----main.py
 |---module1
 |  |---subMain.py  
 |  |---script1.py  
 |  |---script2.py  
 |  |---submodule1
 |      |---script3.py
 |---module2
    |---script4.py
```

Currently subMain.py imports all scripts from module1 with no problems.
Yet, if I try to run main.py by importing module1 files it fails.

```py
#This works
#subMain.py

from script1 import *

#########
#script1.py
from submodule1.script3 import *
```

```py
#This does not work
#main.py

#So far so good
from module1.script1 import *


#########

#script1.py
#this fails
from submodule1.script3 import *

#If I change it to the following, it works
from module1.submodule1.script3 import *
```

Is there a way to have script1 always work (no failure when including script3) without changing the import line?

Comment: The way you want to access the script3 in main.oy file without mentioning mudule1.submodule1 is impossible. importing files or functions from other files must be in the order which they are structured in the project folders.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured the best way to do what I wanted was to build a wheel.
I need to import that same class into several projects and a wheel enables me to fix bugs only in one convenient location and reimport the de-bugged package on each project.

Answer (score -1):

I actually found a workaround, maybe not the cleanest, but I got inspired by C++ `#ifdef` guards.

Basically I check the `__name__` variable.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__" :
   from script1 import scriptObject as scriptObject 
elif __name__ == "__main__" :
   from module1.script1 import scriptObject as scriptObject
else :
    raise Exception(f"__name__ = {__name__} is not a valid guard! Make sure project indentation is correct.")
```

Comment: You should use relative path while accessing module, as the program needs to know where to import from. Your answer to raise exception if module import failed is not a solution. Try this link: https://towardsthecloud.com/get-relative-path-python